# My div won't become scrollable after opening child details elements

Tags: html, css, scroll, media-queries

While on a Desktop, opening the `details` elements does not cause the `#list-wrapper` element to become scrollable. I can't remember all of the things I have tried. The whole idea is that the header and form stay in place while the `#list-wrapper` element can scroll. I have made a simpler version of this work and I can't seem to spot where I'm going wrong.

```
<html lang="en">
    <title>Length Of Stay</title>
  </head>
  <body id="body">
    <div id="page">
      <header id="head"><h1>LENGTH OF STAY</h1></header>
      <main>
        <form
          class="form"
          id="input-form"
          action="los/create"
          method="post"
          autocomplete="off"
        >
          <label
            >NAME<input
              type="text"
              name="name"
              maxlength="12"
              placeholder="Animal's name"
              required="required" /></label
          ><label
            >ID #
            <input
              type="text"
              name="id"
              maxlength="8"
              placeholder="Animal's ID number"
              required="required" /></label
          ><label
            >SPECIES<select name="species" required="required">
              <option
                value=""
                disabled="disabled"
                hidden="hidden"
                selected="selected"
              >
                Select one...
              </option>
              <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
              <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
              <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select></label
          ><label
            >DATE<input
              type="date"
              name="date-of-entry"
              value="2020-10-19"
              required="required" /></label
          ><label
            >SHELTER<select name="shelter" required="required">
              <option
                value=""
                disabled="disabled"
                hidden="hidden"
                selected="selected"
              >
                Select one...
              </option>
              <option value="1">Shelter 1</option>
              <option value="2">Shelter 2</option>
            </select></label
          ><label
            >AREA<select name="area" required="required">
              <option
                value=""
                disabled="disabled"
                hidden="hidden"
                selected="selected"
              >
                Select one...
              </option>
              <option value="F">Shelter Floor (F)</option>
              <option value="Q">Quarantine (Q)</option>
            </select></label
          ><label
            >NOTE<textarea name="notes" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></label
          ><input class="button" type="submit" />
          <hr id="hr" />
        </form>
        <div id="toggle-wrapper">
          <input
            class="toggle"
            id="first-shelter"
            type="button"
            value="Show sh2 First"
          /><input
            class="toggle"
            id="form-visibility"
            type="button"
            value="Show Input Form"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="list-wrapper">
          <div id="list-header">
            <div id="header-name">NAME</div>
            <div id="header-los">LOS</div>
            <div id="header-date">SPECIES</div>
            <div id="headter-shelter">SHELTER</div>
          </div>
          <div class="list" id="sh1-list"></div>
          <hr id="divider" />
          <div class="list" id="sh2-list">
            <details>
              <summary class="sh2 F">
                <div class="status-bar">
                  <div class="status name">Emma</div>
                  <div class="status red">42</div>
                  <div class="status">Cat</div>
                  <div class="status">sh2</div>
                </div>
              </summary>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="left-panel">
                  <div class="info-display">
                    <div class="inDate info">IN DATE: 2020-09-08</div>
                    <div class="id info">ID: A45461728</div>
                    <div class="shelter info">SHELTER: sh2</div>
                    <div class="area info">AREA: F</div>
                  </div>
                  <p>NOTES: Bonded with Kaitlynn.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                  <form action="los/delete" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8521a66480ea700973abcd"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/delete.svg"
                      alt="delete this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/edit" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8521a66480ea700973abcd"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/edit.svg"
                      alt="edit this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/foster" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8521a66480ea700973abcd"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/home.svg"
                      alt="change this record to in-foster"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary class="sh2 F">
                <div class="status-bar">
                  <div class="status name">Kaitlynn</div>
                  <div class="status red">42</div>
                  <div class="status">Cat</div>
                  <div class="status">sh2</div>
                </div>
              </summary>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="left-panel">
                  <div class="info-display">
                    <div class="inDate info">IN DATE: 2020-09-08</div>
                    <div class="id info">ID: A45461764</div>
                    <div class="shelter info">SHELTER: sh2</div>
                    <div class="area info">AREA: F</div>
                  </div>
                  <p>NOTES: Bonded with Emma.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                  <form action="los/delete" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8521f96480ea700973abce"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/delete.svg"
                      alt="delete this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/edit" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8521f96480ea700973abce"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/edit.svg"
                      alt="edit this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/foster" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8521f96480ea700973abce"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/home.svg"
                      alt="change this record to in-foster"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary class="sh2 Q">
                <div class="status-bar">
                  <div class="status name">Lily</div>
                  <div class="status orange">8</div>
                  <div class="status">Cat</div>
                  <div class="status">sh2</div>
                </div>
              </summary>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="left-panel">
                  <div class="info-display">
                    <div class="inDate info">IN DATE: 2020-10-12</div>
                    <div class="id info">ID: A147765</div>
                    <div class="shelter info">SHELTER: sh2</div>
                    <div class="area info">AREA: Q</div>
                  </div>
                  <p>
                    NOTES: No resident pets. Must go to experienced fosters
                    only.
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                  <form action="los/delete" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8522f36480ea700973abcf"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/delete.svg"
                      alt="delete this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/edit" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8522f36480ea700973abcf"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/edit.svg"
                      alt="edit this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/foster" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8522f36480ea700973abcf"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/home.svg"
                      alt="change this record to in-foster"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary class="sh2 Q">
                <div class="status-bar">
                  <div class="status name">GRENDEL</div>
                  <div class="status red">29</div>
                  <div class="status">Dog</div>
                  <div class="status">sh2</div>
                </div>
              </summary>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="left-panel">
                  <div class="info-display">
                    <div class="inDate info">IN DATE: 2020-09-21</div>
                    <div class="id info">ID: A45561172</div>
                    <div class="shelter info">SHELTER: sh2</div>
                    <div class="area info">AREA: Q</div>
                  </div>
                  <p>NOTES: Medical foster</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                  <form action="los/delete" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8523a06480ea700973abd0"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/delete.svg"
                      alt="delete this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/edit" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8523a06480ea700973abd0"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/edit.svg"
                      alt="edit this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/foster" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8523a06480ea700973abd0"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/home.svg"
                      alt="change this record to in-foster"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary class="sh2 Q">
                <div class="status-bar">
                  <div class="status name">Beowolf</div>
                  <div class="status red">29</div>
                  <div class="status">Dog</div>
                  <div class="status">sh2</div>
                </div>
              </summary>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="left-panel">
                  <div class="info-display">
                    <div class="inDate info">IN DATE: 2020-09-21</div>
                    <div class="id info">ID: A4550752</div>
                    <div class="shelter info">SHELTER: sh2</div>
                    <div class="area info">AREA: Q</div>
                  </div>
                  <p>NOTES: Medical Foster</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                  <form action="los/delete" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8524046480ea700973abd1"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/delete.svg"
                      alt="delete this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/edit" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8524046480ea700973abd1"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/edit.svg"
                      alt="edit this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/foster" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8524046480ea700973abd1"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/home.svg"
                      alt="change this record to in-foster"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary class="sh2 F">
                <div class="status-bar">
                  <div class="status name">Sweet Pea</div>
                  <div class="status red">28</div>
                  <div class="status">Dog</div>
                  <div class="status">sh2</div>
                </div>
              </summary>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="left-panel">
                  <div class="info-display">
                    <div class="inDate info">IN DATE: 2020-09-22</div>
                    <div class="id info">ID: A44416615</div>
                    <div class="shelter info">SHELTER: sh2</div>
                    <div class="area info">AREA: F</div>
                  </div>
                  <p>NOTES: Behavior. Bite Waiver.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                  <form action="los/delete" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8525086480ea700973abd2"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/delete.svg"
                      alt="delete this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/edit" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8525086480ea700973abd2"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/edit.svg"
                      alt="edit this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/foster" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8525086480ea700973abd2"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/home.svg"
                      alt="change this record to in-foster"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary class="sh2 F">
                <div class="status-bar">
                  <div class="status name">Serenity</div>
                  <div class="status orange">12</div>
                  <div class="status">Dog</div>
                  <div class="status">sh2</div>
                </div>
              </summary>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="left-panel">
                  <div class="info-display">
                    <div class="inDate info">IN DATE: 2020-10-08</div>
                    <div class="id info">ID: A45143898</div>
                    <div class="shelter info">SHELTER: sh2</div>
                    <div class="area info">AREA: F</div>
                  </div>
                  <p>NOTES: No resident pets.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                  <form action="los/delete" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8525986480ea700973abd3"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/delete.svg"
                      alt="delete this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/edit" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8525986480ea700973abd3"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/edit.svg"
                      alt="edit this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/foster" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8525986480ea700973abd3"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/home.svg"
                      alt="change this record to in-foster"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </details>
            <details>
              <summary class="sh2 F">
                <div class="status-bar">
                  <div class="status name">Baylee</div>
                  <div class="status orange">8</div>
                  <div class="status">Dog</div>
                  <div class="status">sh2</div>
                </div>
              </summary>
              <div class="detail">
                <div class="left-panel">
                  <div class="info-display">
                    <div class="inDate info">IN DATE: 2020-10-12</div>
                    <div class="id info">ID: A45126803</div>
                    <div class="shelter info">SHELTER: sh2</div>
                    <div class="area info">AREA: F</div>
                  </div>
                  <p>
                    NOTES: Came into shelter 7/27. Let's find this girl a great
                    home!
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="icons">
                  <form action="los/delete" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8526146480ea700973abd4"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/delete.svg"
                      alt="delete this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/edit" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8526146480ea700973abd4"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/edit.svg"
                      alt="edit this record"
                    />
                  </form>
                  <form action="los/foster" method="post">
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="id"
                      value="5f8526146480ea700973abd4"
                    /><input
                      class="icon"
                      type="image"
                      src="los/home.svg"
                      alt="change this record to in-foster"
                    />
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </details>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
    <script src="los/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: acumin-pro, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

#page {
  background-color: #47484d;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: acumin-pro-extra-condensed, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#list-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#input-form {
  display: none;
}

.form {
  grid-area: "form";
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 13px;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: azure;
}

label input,
select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 3px;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
}

.button-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  height: 34px;
  width: 34%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 3px;
}

hr {
  margin: 13px 0;
  width: 90%;
  color: white;
}

#toggle-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.toggle {
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#list-header {
  width: 90%;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 5px 3px 21px;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

details {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 5px 0;
  color: black;
}

summary {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.status-bar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80%;
}

.status {
  width: 13px;
}

.name {
  width: 55px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.detail {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 0 8px 13px;
}

.left-panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 90%;
}

.info-display {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.info {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.icons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.icons form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
  padding: 3px;
  width: 75%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 89%;
  padding: 8px;
  margin-top: 34px;
}

.PA {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #003057;
}

.RWC {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #4e7e96;
}

.Q {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #ff5555;
}

.true {
  background-color: #c4c4c4;
}

.green {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.orange {
  color: darkorange;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.red {
  color: firebrick;
  font-weight: bold;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  body {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #page {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 6fr;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: unset;
    align-items: unset;
  }

  #head {
    background-color: #47484d;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 2fr 3fr;
    overflow: hidden;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: start;
  }

  #input-form {
    display: flex;
  }

  #list-wrapper {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  #toggle-wrapper,
  #hr {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change :
OverFlow:hidden;
to:
Overflow:auto;

Comment: you are welcome bro, happy that helped you ^_^